# CGContextDrawPDFPage Leak 100%

Tags: pdf, core-graphics, memory-leaks

I try to Draw a pdf with CoreGraphics, everything work fine but in instrument there is a 100% leak on : CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page2);
I release with CGPDFDocumentRelease(); everytime i use CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL();
There is any solution to release : CGContextDrawPDFPage ?

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
        {
        if (state == 0) {
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
        [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
        CGContextGetCTM(ctx);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 45, -rect.size.height);
        CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(((CFURLRef)url));
        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, currentPage);
        CGRect mediaRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFCropBox);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, (678) / mediaRect.size.width,
        (rect.size.height )  / (mediaRect.size.height));
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
        CGContextSetRenderingIntent(ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
        }
        else
        {
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
        [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));

        CGContextGetCTM(ctx);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 6, -rect.size.height);

        CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(((CFURLRef)url));
        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, currentPage);


        CGRect mediaRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFCropBox);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, (497) / mediaRect.size.width,
        (rect.size.height )  / (mediaRect.size.height));

        // draw it
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
        CGContextSetRenderingIntent(ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

        //

        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

        CGContextGetCTM(ctx);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 506, -rect.size.height);

        CGPDFDocumentRef pdf2 = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(((CFURLRef)url));
        CGPDFPageRef page2 = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf2, (currentPage + 1));



        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, (497) / mediaRect.size.width,
        (rect.size.height )  / (mediaRect.size.height));

        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
        CGContextSetRenderingIntent(ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        //Leak 100%
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page2);
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf2);
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
        }
    }
```

And I don't know why. Any idea?
This is the only leak of my app :(
I don't see where the leak come from :s

PS : state = 0 = portrait orientation
state = 1 = landscape so I draw 2 pages in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not releasing the CGPDFPageRef instances you're getting from CGPDFDocumentGetPage.

```
CGPDFPageRelease(page);
```

Add that for page and page2 at the appropriate locations.

Comment: i have similar problem and i released pageReff but its crashing.i think the pdf page we get from CGPDFGetPageReff() is an auto released objcet.

Comment: @Hariprasad Agreed. You should only `CGPDFPageRelease` to offset any `CGPDFPageRetain` you may have done. But if you only did `CGPDFDocumentGetPage`, you have autoreleased object and should _not_ `CGPDFPageRelease`.